# Declare a global variable like jQuery inline with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to use TypeScript to only analyze JavaScript files (during a transition period, possibly). I've stumbled upon the problem of defining global variables inline in JSDoc or similar. It's not described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html

By the way, the syntax to do it in Flow is:

```
/*:: declare var $: Object */
```

Is there something similar for tsc?

Edit: Or, alternatively, the possibility to include a global declaration file when analyzing .js files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not supported, but there's a discussion about it here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15626

Also a blog post: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/declaring-global-variables-in-typescript

Otherwise, add a `globals.d.ts` and include it when type-checking. For jQuery, something like:

```
declare function $(str: string): Object
```